# What type in C# stores 64-bit double-precision floating point values?

Tags: c#

A previous question I asked indicated that this was 64 bit (8 byte) double-precision floating point type.

What is the equivalent of this in C#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) which is an alias for the [`System.Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double) type:

> The **double** keyword denotes a simple type that stores 64-bit floating-point values.
>
> —[MSDN: double (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Comment: An external link here is dead. You can find a historical copy [at the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100213160108/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(VS.71).aspx). A current reference that gives similar information is [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Updated the links. I wouldn't have minded you editing directly, either :)